# Creating Spinner in excel sheet using apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Apache POI is used in our application. Due to the specific business reason we have been asked to insert the spinners in the generated excel documents.

[image: example]

Is it possible to create a number and date spinners in excel using the java Apache poi?

Comment: Please explain your question briefly and show your effort...

Comment: you would need to display the spinner in your Swing application. The generated Excel is just the end result of the process

Comment: @Sankumarsingh Which details would you like to have?

Comment: @Oliver Watkins Due to the tricky business case we do need spinners inside the excel

Comment: oh, too tricky for me then :)